# Protobuf vs Json [Flattening vs Transformations]

Tags: json, protocol-buffers, transform

I am new to protobuf but AFAIK protbuf makes transmitting messages over the network faster due to compression all benefits.

My question is if we have received the message and deserialized it to either proto or json, and all I need to do is massive transformations or flattening the data etc which one should be faster Json vs Proto and if anyone has used existing libraries for the same.